# Помогите с регулярным выражением (удаление всего между <a и > включительно)

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть строка которая содержит ссылки
мне нужно удалить открывающий тег со всеми его атрибутами и стилями
например такой:

```
<a target="_blank" атрибуты, стили>
```

удалить все между `<a и >` влкючительно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

регулярное выражение: `<a (.*?)>`

Comment: а нельзя как то захватить еще и сами тег одной регуляркой?

Comment: можно просто удалить всё найденное этим кодом.

Comment: $posttext = preg_replace('<a (.*?)>', '', $posttext);
написал вот так, в итоге после прохода у меня остается <a>

Comment: А может остаётся `</a>`? Потому как это код  должен вырезать. А если вдруг нет - должен быть пробел перед последней скобкой: `<a >`

Comment: пробел после a в моем случае не нужен был

Comment: Я забыл, что в php надо обрамлять код слешам. Вот так по идее должно сработать: `$posttext = preg_replace('/<a (.*?)>/', '', $posttext);`

Comment: может и это знаете как сделать?) http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/614754/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%91-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0/614761?noredirect=1#comment848400_614761