# Как удалить всё после определенного слова (символа)?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть текст в котором присутствует словосочетание "НОВОСТИ ПО ТЕМЕ".

Как удалить словосочетание и весь текст после него?
А желательно и вместе с `<p>` который его обрамляет

```
 <p>
        <b>В авиакомпании «Оренбуржье» подтвердили информацию о завершении программы субсидируемых авиапереквозок в ПФО и Оренбургской области, а также рассказали о том, как компания намерена работать в новых финансовых условиях.</b></p>
    <p>
        Как писал RIA56, Росавиация ранее опубликовала программу субсидируемых авиаперевозок по регионам России. Самара, Саратов и Оренбург в нее не вошли. Не попал в нее и оренбургский авиаперевозчик.</p>
    <p>
        - Программа развития региональных авиаперевозок в Приволжском федеральном округе, предусматривающая субсидирование ряда межрегиональных направлений, завершилась, - говорится в сообщении «Оренбуржья».</p>
    <p>
        По словам представителя перевозчика, цены на перевозки в городах ПФО после отмены субсидий не изменятся. При этом будет сокращена частота выполнения рейсов.</p>
    <p>
        - «Оренбуржье» продолжает реализацию задачи обеспечения доступности внутренних региональных перевозок пассажиров по обслуживаемым ранее маршрутам в полном объеме, в том числе и на маршрутах внутри Приволжского Федерального округа, без изменения тарифной политики, корректируя лишь частоты вылетов, - отмечается в заявлении компании.</p>
    <p>
        Также в «Оренбуржье» подчеркнули, что сейчас обсуждается возможность включения полетов авиакомпании на маршрутах ПФО в одну из программ с государственной поддержкой. О чем именно идет речь в авиакомпании пока не уточнили.</p>
    <p>
        <b>НОВОСТИ ПО ТЕМЕ:</b></p>
    <p>
        Авиакомпания «Оренбуржье» начнет летать за границу</p>
    <p>
        «Оренбуржье» соединило города ХМАО</p>
    <p>
        Авиакомпания&nbsp;«Оренбуржье» запускает дополнительные рейсы в Екатеринбург</p>
    <p>
        Оренбургский аэропорт пополнят еще два чешских самолета</p>
```

Comment: Что вы уже пытались сделать сами ? А то ведь из ответа на предыдущий ваш вопрос запросто можно понять как это решать ...

Comment: $posttext = preg_replace('<b>НОВО(.*?)', '', $posttext); - ошибка;;;  $posttext = preg_replace('<p>
 <b>НОВО(.*?)', '', $posttext);- тоже

Comment: а еще кучу примеров в гугле уже посотрел, либо ничего либо ошибка. Пока нет времени чтобы подробно изучить

Comment: конечно, ведь любые регулярки надо заключать в косые (или другие символы) `preg_replace('/<p>\s*<b>НОВО.*/','')` правда там могут быть особенности работы из за переводов кареток, если они есть

Answer (score 1):

«Парсить» регулярками HTML можно до тех пока кровь из глаз пойдёт.
**Регулярка не может** учитывать структуру документа.

Для этого есть специализированные библиотеки, как пример [DomCrawler](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html)

---

P.S.

Парадоксально, но нативно PHP не поддерживает HTML5. Т.к. libxml2, которая используется под капотом обрабатывать его тоже не умеет.

Comment: пользуюсь phpQuery выбрал блок внутри которого осталось только то что выше

Comment: @ЕвгенийШевцов, необходимо обрабатывать каждый элемент, его контент и атрибуты отдельно

Comment: и в коде выше кажется нет html5, все что мне нужно это удалить лишнее после "НОВОСТЬ ПО ТЕМЕ"

Comment: @ЕвгенийШевцов, в другой раз окажется, что внутри `<p>` оказался - неразрывный пробел, внутри жирного подчёркнутый, картинка или вообще пустота.

Comment: это шаблонная часть страницы, поэтому я и хочу от нее избавиться, на каждой странице Есть новость по теме, ее я хочу взять за основу чтобы удалить все включая ее, код страницы очень простой, больше на ней ничего нет кроме того что вставил в примере

Comment: неужели нет способа чтобы удалить все символы после НОВОСТИ ПО ТЕМЕ включая переносы строк табуляции пробелы? я думю что в ответе выше этого перечисления не хватает но с регулярками не знаком уже полтора часа мучаюсь пытаюсь понять как составить такую универсальную строчку

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_replace("/<p>([^А-я]*)НОВОСТИ ПО ТЕМЕ:(.*)/", "", $input);
```

[Тест регулярки](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/izA)

Comment: удалил только само словосочетание, а весь текст после него остался

Comment: @ЕвгенийШевцов preg_replace нажмите

Comment: вот сами посотрите http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/izD

Comment: может сначала нужно почистить этот документ от перевода строки или еще чего то а вторым действием применять уже то что вы написали??

Comment: нет, это онлайн-тест, он работает по-другому.